# Performance penalty when overriding Numpy's __array_function__() method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclassing

I wrote an array-like class 'Vector' which behaves like an 'np.ndarray' but has a few extra attributes and methods to be used in a geometry engine (which are omitted here).

The MVP below overrides '__ array_function __()' to ensure that a Vector object is returned when using the np.dot function.

When I benchmarked my code against plain-vanilla np.array objects, I noticed a severe performance hit:

```py
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit


class Vector(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        return np.array(input_array).view(cls)

    def __array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs):
        if func == np.dot:
            out = np.dot(np.asarray(args[0]), np.asarray(args[1]))
            return out.view(Vector)
```

Benchmark:

```py
v = Vector([1, 1, 1])
I = np.identity(3)

print(type(np.dot(I, v)))  # Make sure it returns the correct type.

# Create a np.array and Vector object.
A = np.random.random((100, 3))
V = A.view(Vector)

# Compare np.dot speed.
print(timeit(lambda: np.dot(I, A.T)))
print(timeit(lambda: np.dot(I, V.T)))
```

The above code outputs:

```
<class '__main__.Vector'>
1.207045791001292
2.063941927997803
```

Indicating a 70 % performance hit. Is this expected? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way around this (I'm only interested in np.dot and np.cross)?

If not, I'm afraid I'll have to abandon my custom classes.

Comment: If you remove the `__array_function__`, your timing difference is the same. Could this come from some internal conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected since the target arrays are very small and the overhead of calling a pure-Python function is big compared to the computation time taken by `np.dot` on a basic array.

---

Indeed, `np.dot(I, A.T)` takes just about few microseconds: 1.7 µs on my machine. A significant part of the time is lost in Numpy overheads and the actual computation should take just a fraction of this execution time. `np.dot(I, V.T)` has to call the pure-Python function `__array_function__` and this function takes about 1.2 us. The overall runtime is thus 2.9 us, hence a 70% slower execution.

`__array_function__` is a bit slow because it is **interpreted** (assuming you use the standard CPython interpreter) while usual Numpy functions are written in C and so they are compiled to native code. Interpreted codes are significantly slower (due to nearly no optimizations, dynamic typing, many dynamic allocations, object wrapping, etc.) not to mention the 2 calls to `np.asarray` takes a significant additional time compared to just calling `np.dot` directly.

One solution to reduce the overhead is to use Cython. Cython can compile a pure-Python function to native code. The compiled code can be much faster if type annotation are present. That being said, the benefit of using Cython here is limited. Indeed, **half the overhead comes from the Numpy internals when calling `np.dot`**. This is certainly because Numpy has to create Python objects (eg. `args`) so to pass them to the pure-Python function and also because Numpy and CPython has to perform few check (eg. check the function `__array_function__` is actually valid). AFAIK, there is not much you can do about this Numpy overhead.

In the end, since >75% of the execution time of `np.dot(I, A.T)` is already overheads it is certainly better to rewrite the code calling this expression so calls are **vectorized**. Indeed, calling `__array_function__` once is not really a problem. This means you may need to write a class to manage many vectors. If the vectors are of different size, then the overhead can still be significant (Numpy is not great for that).